# How far does the man have to walk down the beam in order to tip the beam off fulcrum A?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, equilibrium

[image]

I have set the sum of the forces in the y equal to zero and calculating the torque around B, I get that he walks 7.9. I don't have an answer key, but I don't believe this is the correct answer. I did a similar problem that assumed that the contributing force from A was zero. Would this be a false assumption to make?

Comment: The point is that at some distance from B, the torque from the man's weight will equal the torque from the weight. since the man's mass is 3 times larger than the weight, he will exert the same torque at a distance 3 times smaller from B, so 5/3 on the other side which is 10+5/3 distance from A. The force from A is only relevant when all weight is supported on the left side of B, but when man and weight are in equilibrium A plays no role.

Comment: @rmhleo: I think you haven't taken the weight of the beam into account, which also provides clockwise torque around B.

Comment: I am sorry, I just noticed that the bar has a weight per length, this changes the problem. Now when the man is at 5/3 the torque will be higher because of the additional mass of the bar. In fact the bar adds a torque which is depends on the square of the distance. Still the contribution from A will be zero for the solution you are searching, which demands equilibrium between both sides.

Comment: Definitely a case made for the SI system: how does 15' relate to   1 ft? ;-)

Comment: So the man has to be on the right side at a distance that compensates the torques from the weight and the beams on the left side. So he has to walk a distance further from 5/3 that compensates the difference between left and hand side of the bar (left is 10' and right is 5') 25/2*(10^2-5^2)=25*75/2. The extra distance d contributes to the torque on left by 150*d, so making these two equal you get 25/4=6.25'. So the man has to stand at 5/3+6.25=7.916666 from B. Pretty close to your answer, so I guess your method is correct.

Comment: I just assumed 15' are 15ft. Is it correct?

Comment: @rmhleo I assumed 15' and 15ft are the same, yes. Your explanation about the relevancy of the force from A was helpful, thank you. Since there is only 5 feet left past B, is it impossible for the man to stay on the beam to tip it if the equilibrium is at 7.9 feet past B?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @slick1092 , you should review your reasoning. I encourage you to write your own answer based on your new insight and un-accept the one you chose, because is wrong

Comment: I realized the chosen answer is correct. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @JohnRennie The question wasn't about if my work was right, but if my underlying assumption about the work was right. rmhleo's explanation made a lot of sense and helped me understand and Daniel Griscom helped as well with his answer and discussion with rhmleo. PS, I don't have peers to help me with this as I am studying for a technical interview and trying to review several years old knowledge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have three weights, and for ease of calculation we'll measure from fulcrum $B$:

Mass: $50lbs$ at $-5ft$

Beam: $25{lbs\over{ft}}\times 15ft = 375lbs$ centered at $-2.5ft$ (can be considered a point weight for this problem)

Man: $150lbs$ at $Xft$, where $X$ is where the beam starts tipping.

So, when the man is at some position X (we're guessing it's positive), his leverage will be the opposite of the mass and beam's total leverage.

Mass's leverage is $50lbs\times-5ft = -250ft·lbs$

Beam's leverage is $375lbs\times-2.5ft = -937.5ft·lbs$

So, mass plus beam gives a leverage of $-1187.5ft·lbs$.

Man's leverage is $150lbs\times Xft = -(-1187.5 ft·lbs)$

Divide both sides by $150lbs$, and you get $X = {1187.5 ft·lbs\over150lbs} = 7.917ft$

**BUT!** we chose as an origin fulcrum $B$, which is $10ft$ from where the man starts walking. So, the man has to walk a total of $17.917ft$ before he tips over into oblivion.

**Edit:** Note that, for this to work, the man must walk $2.917ft$ **beyond** the end of the beam in order to start the beam tipping. That, plus the poor drawing (where the $10ft$ to the left of $B$ looks shorter than the $5ft$ to the right of $B$) leads me to think this problem wasn't very well designed.

Comment: The contribution from the beam is incorrect. Each portion of mass dl has a different distance from B and therefore contributes differently to the torque. The torque contribution from the beam is $\lambda l^2/2$ where lambda is the mass density.

Comment: Nope. Consider the beam alone, and balance it at its $CG$ on a second (weightless) beam that runs from the first beam's $CG$ to $B$. The first beam will experience no torque around its $CG$, and will be equivalent to a $375lbs$ mass at that same point. To keep the first beam up you'll have to apply a torque to the second beam. Now connect the two beams at $B$, which will require no force, and you have exactly the original situation.

Comment: I did not really understand your example. But I am positive that a beam which does not deform, and with a constant linear mass density, will not behave as you say. It will certainly have the CG in the same place as if it were massless, but when balanced over a different point, the part exceeding the other d length, will exceed the torque of the other in $\lambda d^2/2$. This in a sense is like having on that side a mass that weights $\lambda d$ suspended on its mass center $d/2$.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment $\lambda d^2/2$ is wrong. One side torque will exceed the other in $\lambda l d$ where $l$ is the total beam length and $d$ the distance from balance point to CG or COM (the same here). This is consistent with the rest of my comments.

Comment: @rmhleo: if my treating the beam as a point mass is wrong, and your treating the beam as a complete linear element is right, then how come I got the same answer as you?

Comment: And, you say that the torque will be the linear density, times the length, times the distance from the CG to the balance point. Linear density times length equals mass, right? So, you're saying the torque equals the mass times the distance from the CG to the balance point, right? How is that different from what I'm saying?

Comment: Indeed your treatment is equivalent and valid. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @Ernie: any comment?